How to eager load with query join?
I have a code like this:
    $projects = Project::query()
        ->select('projects.*')
        ->join('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
        ->groupBy('projects.id')

So it is a simple join. I want to use eager load on it. I tried
    $projects = Project::with('tasks')->query()
        ->select('projects.*')
        ->join('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
        ->groupBy('projects.id')

But it is not the right syntax.
I checked the documentation too, no success.
How to eager load when it is a custom query with join?

Try this and let me know.
$projects = Project::with('tasks')
    ->select('projects.*')
    ->join('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
    ->groupBy('projects.id')
    ->get();


Syntactically good, but still not eager loading it. I have strict mode enabled and it throw that attempted lazy loading.

Hey did you get any specific error or logs ? If yes then please share it

Just that it does not do eager loading. The problem that join is not compatible with eager loading.

Just a min, there is another relationship to eager load, maybe that is causing this.
